# Java Virtual Machine Launcher Error: Unable to access jarfile bin/Eaters_TankSoar.jar

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I have an AI game we use for class written in Java. It works fine on my Surface Pro with Windows 10 but I cannot get it to work on my HP EliteBook. The error is displayed in a Java popup and says:

`Java Virtual Machine Launcher Error: Unable to access jarfile bin/Eaters_TankSoar.jar`

I have setup identical environments between the two systems including the same (older) version of Java that works fine on the original system. I checked the environment variables, permissions, policy files, etc. I have found several posts with the usual suggestions (launch from same directory, check permissions, Java version, run as admin, etc.) and none have led me to the solution and the file and structure are copied exactly from the working version.

It is launched from a .bat file:

```
@echo off
set SOAR_HOME=%~dp0bin
set PATH=%SOAR_HOME%;%PATH%
start javaw -jar bin\Eaters_TankSoar.jar config\eaters.cnf
```

Is there some sort of security setting for Java in Windows that would prevent this on one machine but not the other? Even though I have found posts mentioning a Java Control Panel, there does not seem to be any such thing in the current version of Windows for this Java version which is:

```
java version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+7)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.1+7, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: Does your current working directory contain the `bin` folder? And does that folder contain the missing JAR file?

Comment: @user207421 yes and yes.

Comment: 'Current working directory' does not mean where the .bat file is located. Many people confuse them. It means the directory you are currently in, as shown by `pwd` or `cd` as appropriate.  And do you have read access to `bin` and the JAR file?

Comment: @user207421 This problem is not related to file hierarchy or permissions issues as I stated in the post. The identical package runs fine on the other machine with the same windows and Java versions.

Comment: Well it has to be one of those things.

Comment: Replace `set SOAR_HOME=%~dp0bin` by `set "SOAR_HOME=%~dp0bin"`. Replace `set PATH=%SOAR_HOME%;%PATH%` by `if "%PATH:~-1%" == ";" (set "PATH=%PATH%%SOAR_HOME%") else set "PATH=%PATH%;%SOAR_HOME%"`. Replace `start javaw -jar bin\Eaters_TankSoar.jar config\eaters.cnf` by `start "" javaw.exe -jar "%~dp0bin\Eaters_TankSoar.jar" "%~dp0config\eaters.cnf"` and this last command line could start working if the directory containing the batch file contains the subdirectories `bin` and `config` with file `Eaters_TankSoar.jar` in subdirectory `bin` and with file `eaters.cnf` in subdirectory `config`.